# I keep getting an InputMismatchException even though all types are correct , what should ido?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Messdaten {
    public static double temperaturInDurchschnitt(Scanner sc){
        int year= 0, month= 0 , day= 0;
        String discription = "";
        double value= 0.0;
        double warmest= -273.15;
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            year= sc.nextInt();
            month= sc.nextInt();
            day= sc.nextInt();
            discription = sc.nextLine();
            if (discription.equals("Temperatur")){
                value= sc.nextDouble();
                sum = sum + value;
                if (value>= warmest){
                    warmest = value;
                }

            }
            value = sc.nextDouble();
        } sc.close();
        System.out.println("highest Temperatur " + "(" + warmest+ ")" + "at" + day+ month+ year);
        return sum/i;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        temperaturInDurchschnitt(sc);
    }

}
```

i am trying to gather the values of temperatur only from a given text:

2018 10 16 Luftdruck 1014.7

2018 10 17 Niederschlag 1.3

2018 10 15 Temperatur 18.2

2018 10 16 Niederschlag 0.0

and return the highest temp at which day .

2018 10 17 Temperatur 16.8

Comment: Please provide the full error message in your question, including the stack trace.

Comment: `value = sc.nextDouble();` reads `2018` from the second line of the input... as a consequence `day= sc.nextInt();` tries to read int from `Niederschlag` causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for reading each line via your `Scanner` is incorrect.  Looking at just this part of your code that is supposed to read a single line:

```
year= sc.nextInt();
month= sc.nextInt();
day= sc.nextInt();
discription = sc.nextLine();
if (discription.equals("Temperatur")){
    value= sc.nextDouble();
    sum = sum + value;
    if (value>= warmest){
        warmest = value;
    }
}
value = sc.nextDouble();
```

When you call `sc.nextLine()`, you've now read the entire rest of the line and assigned it to `discription`. So the check that follow will never be `true`, because even where it should succeed, `discription` will be `Temperatur 16.8`.  But I think you get off track before you ever get there.  When you call `sc.nextDouble()`, you won't get the value at the end of a line, because you've already read the whole line.  Instead, you'll get the year value from the next line.  And now you're out of sync with your incoming data.  I expect that the error comes when you call `nextInt()` to read the `day` value, and you get the description value instead of the day value, which of course, can't be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
        // ...
        double sum = 0.0;
        String line;
        while (!(line = sc.nextLine()).isBlank()) { // 1
            String[] splitLine = line.trim().split(" "); // 2
            discription = splitLine[3];
            if (discription.equals("Temperatur")) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[4]);
                sum = sum + value;
                if (value >= warmest) {
                    warmest = value;
                    year = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]);  //3
                    month = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]);
                    day = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        // ...
```

Remarks:

- `//1` you need to know when to stop reading the input - you can check if the next line is blank for example
- `//2` to avoid the problem mentioned in the comment, I would read the whole line and parse each of the space separated parts to the expected types
- `//3` seems that you want to store the `year`, `month` and `day` of the warmest day, so it should be updated only when you find the higher temperature.